# Efficient setting of properties of multiple vertices in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The functions `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue` can only set a single property of a single vertex, as far as I know. How do I set a property for multiple vertices simultaneously?

In the documentation, they recommend using `Do` to set multiple properties, but I've heard that `Do` is not the most efficient way to do things in *Mathematica*. Are there any alternatives?

**EDIT :** The only approach seems to make several calls to `SetProperty` or `PropertyValue` (which is faster), one call for each distinct vertex property I want to set. From the answers so far it seems that there is no Mathematica equivalent to `SetProperty` or `PropertyValue` that sets several properties of distinct vertices at once. But I'd still hope that something could be done directly on the `Graph` object, bypassing `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue`.

Comment: A meta question: Is the version-8 tag necessary here? `PropertyValue` is new in version 8, but when mma 9 comes along this tag will become redundant...

Comment: @Ajasja I think the version-8 tag is important here. Especially because in Mathematica 8 there are three distinct ways of dealing with graphs: two are the `Combinatorica` package and the `GraphPlot` et al, which have been there at least since version 6; the other is the `Graph` object, which is new to version 8. The tag graphs-and-networks alone would not make this distinction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may be not clear from documentation but `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue` can take "global to graph" specifications to apply simultaneously to all objects

```
Row@{g = CompleteGraph[4, PlotRangePadding -> .2], 
  PropertyValue[g, VertexLabels] = "Name"; g}
```

[image]

and even sets of "global to graph" specifications put in a list:

```
Row@{g = CompleteGraph[12, PlotRangePadding -> .3, ImageSize -> 300], 
  SetProperty[
   g, {VertexSize -> .4, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    VertexStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.4], Green], 
    EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thickness[.02], Opacity[.2], Red]}]}
```

[image]

Also, if you have unique-to-object options you can specify them by other than `Do` means. The documentation has examples of functional programming. For instance, slightly modifying [this example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7cyixcgz0-7j1gro) using `Fold`:

```
Row@{g = CompleteGraph[8, VertexSize -> Large],
  Fold[SetProperty[{#1, #2}, VertexStyle -> ColorData[45, #2]] &, g, Range[1, 8]]}
```

[image]

Or [this example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0g7gcyjhooq-h67ta5) with `Do` that you've seen, can be done with `Map`:

```
Row@{g = CompleteGraph[15, VertexSize ->Large], 
    (PropertyValue[{g, #[[1]]}, VertexStyle] = #[[2]]) & /@ 
     Transpose[{Range[15], ColorData[1, "ColorList"]}]; g}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will improve efficiency, in this paricular case. FP offers speed advantage when array indexing or similar frequent operations are involved, since it pushes more of that into the kernel. This does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The question has reference to `Do`, and for now my sole intent was to show other functions usage.

Comment: The question's title implies that efficiency is central here, which is why I made this comment.

Comment: `Scan` might be even better than `Map`, since the only use if map is for the side effects.

Comment: I had tried similar approaches. What I was looking for was an alternative that didn't involve several *distinct* calls to `SetProperty` or `PropertyValue`, perhaps by avoiding those functions altogether and doing some rule-replacement combo on the Graph directly. Why isn't something like that implemented in Mathematica?

Comment: I +1 @LeonidShifrin comments because I think he gets what I am asking for, although I see that my question did not pin-point it. I should also clarify that I am interested in modifying individual vertex properties, not "global graph" properties. I +1 both answers because they do contain useful information, even though I had already tried what they suggested.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think you will get much better performance using functional approaches here, since the call to `SetProperty` is the bottleneck instead of the `Do` loop.
Anyway it says in the documentation that `PropertyValue` is much faster than `SetProperty`. We can check both assumptions:

```
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight] = RandomReal[], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}]

(* ==> {0.016, Null} *)

g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  SetProperty[{g, v}, VertexWeight -> RandomReal[]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}]

(* ==> {2.25, Null} *)

(*Try scan*)
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexWeight] = RandomReal[]) &, 
  VertexList[g]]

(* ==> {0.031, Null} *)

g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Scan[(SetProperty[{g, #}, VertexWeight -> RandomReal[]]) &, 
  VertexList[g]]

(* ==> {2.625, Null} *)
```

From this we see that for this example `PropertyValue` is indeed much better and that using `Scan` has no benefits.

Answer (score 4):

The information concerning `SetProperty` and `PropertyValue` timings aren't the full story! The `SetProperty` invokes no persistent side-effect (one must assign with it to keep the edited graph!) where as `PropertyValue` does edit the object (in-place).

Given that this performance testing is to create an graph object one wants to do more with I'm going to present the following timing results (from my crappy work laptop):

```
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight] = RandomReal[], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}] (*{24.109375`,Null} *)
MemberQ[PropertyList[g], VertexWeight] (*True*)

g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  SetProperty[{g, v}, VertexWeight -> RandomReal[]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}] (*{0.1875`,Null}*)
MemberQ[PropertyList[g], VertexWeight] (*False*)

g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  g = SetProperty[{g, v}, VertexWeight -> RandomReal[]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}] (*{23.859375`,Null}*)
MemberQ[PropertyList[g], VertexWeight] (*True*)
```

Note the `PropertyList` in the second case left no side effect of a graph with `VertexWeight`s assigned!

I've noticed the same timings irrespective of the method (`Scan`, `Map`, `Fold`, `Do`) used to invoke list processing. The performance timings appear commensurate and I'm guessing because of the underlying implementation one just can't avoid the performance hit of assigning a new graph each time any single `VertexWeight` is updated.

I'm yet to see what impact this has when one wants to pack more complex objects into `VertexWeight`s such as `EmpiricalDistribution` (my current goal). My guess though is that providing a graph with everything it needs to be endowed with at instantiation is the only way to avoid performance problems on large graphs.

Answer (score 1):

It just got even more interesting. I tried assigning a list to a `VertexWeight` and couldn't. I could however assign an `EmpiricalDistribution` (which is odd as it has a lot of structure inside it).

Check this the following timings though:

```
Clear[g]
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight] = 
   EmpiricalDistribution[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000}]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}]
MemberQ[PropertyList[g], VertexWeight]

(* Out[3]= {28.7813, Null} *)

(* Out[4]= True *)

Clear[g]
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  PropertyValue[{g, v}, "MyVertexWeight"] = 
   EmpiricalDistribution[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000}]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}]
MemberQ[PropertyList[{g, 1}], "MyVertexWeight"]
PropertyList[g]
PropertyList[{g, 1}]

(* Out[7]= {0.171875, Null} *)

(* Out[8]= True *)

(* Out[9]= {GraphHighlight, GraphHighlightStyle, GraphLayout, \
GraphStyle, EdgeShapeFunction, EdgeStyle, VertexCoordinates, \
VertexShapeFunction, VertexShape, VertexSize, VertexStyle} *)

(* Out[10]= {"MyVertexWeight", VertexCoordinates, VertexShape, \
VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle} *)

Clear[g]
g = CycleGraph[1000];
Timing@Do[
  g = SetProperty[{g, v}, 
    "MyVertexWeight" -> 
     EmpiricalDistribution[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000}]]], {v, 
   VertexList[g]}]
MemberQ[PropertyList[{g, 1}], "MyVertexWeight"]
PropertyList[g]
PropertyList[{g, 1}]

(* {0.296875, Null} *)

(* True  *)

(* Out[15]= {GraphHighlight, GraphHighlightStyle, GraphLayout, \
GraphStyle, EdgeShapeFunction, EdgeStyle, VertexCoordinates, \
VertexShapeFunction, VertexShape, VertexSize, VertexStyle} *)

(* Out[16]= {"MyVertexWeight", VertexCoordinates, VertexShape, \
VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle} *)
```

It appears that if you create your own graph properties they behave much faster. It also turned out that you CAN assign lists to them in addition to anything else.

Funny thing is now after all that `PropertyValue` appears to be faster than `SetProperty` even with the re-assignment (and modulo `Scan`, `Map`,`Do`).