# Why are SetProperty and PropertyValue not working here?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, syntax

I have a very simple graph, a loop:

```
x = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {1, 10, 30, 60}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

Now, I want to change the values of its EdgeWeights. First, let's make sure I can even fetch them:

```
In[105]:= PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]

Out[105]= {1, 10, 30, 60}
```

Yay! Now let's try and change them:

```
In[110]:= PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] = {20, 49, 87, 5}

Out[110]= {20, 49, 87, 5}
```

Cool, now let's check their values.

```
In[111]:= PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]

Out[111]= {1, 10, 30, 60}
```

Wait, what... That's strange, because in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5838/11613) answer, that syntax is working...

Okay, let's try SetProperty, that's what it's for.

```
SetProperty[x, EdgeWeight -> {20, 49, 87, 5}]
<<Returns graph of x, but with initial weights as the edge labels, but ok>>
```

Now let's check...

```
In[116]:= PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]

Out[116]= {1, 10, 30, 60}
```

Um...

Let's try checking just the first value?

```
In[117]:= PropertyValue[{x, 1}, EdgeWeight]

Out[117]= $Failed
```

What's going on here? EdgeWeight is in the PropertyList@x. Is this somehow a bug?

I'm sure I'm missing something but I just wanted to make it clear that I tried a few things. What am I missing?

For posterity, I'm using version 10.0.2.0 on Windows 8 (which would explain the bug).

Comment: If you use `x = SetProperty[x, EdgeWeight -> {20, 49, 87, 5}]`, then  `PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]` gives the expected result. The docs [SetProperty >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetProperty.html) says: _SetProperty will produce a **new** graph with a modified property value._

Comment: You need to use `PropertyValue[{x, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight]` instead of  `PropertyValue[{x, 1}, EdgeWeight]`. In the latter is `{x,1}`  interpreted as vertex `1` in graph  `x` which does not have an `EdgeWeight` property.

Comment: In version 9.0.1.0 (windows 8, 64-bit) `PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] = {20, 49, 87, 5};PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] ` returns ` {20, 49, 87, 5}` as expected.

Comment: Ahhh... I swear I tried that, but I'll make sure to try it tomorrow. But why isn't setting PropertyValue = somevalue working?

Comment: @kguler, thanks again. Though I must say, the syntax of having to use a<->b as the identifier in PropertyValue is weird, because the EdgeWeights are just an ordered list identified by an integer index, like EdgeList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64-bit)

In version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 64-bit), both `PropertyValue` and `SetProperty` work as expected:

```
x = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4},
  EdgeWeight -> {1, 10, 30, 60}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**PropertyValue**

```
PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]
(* {1, 10, 30, 60} *)
PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] = {20, 49, 87, 5};
PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]
(* {20, 49, 87, 5} *)
```

**SetProperty**

The docs [SetProperty >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetProperty.html) says:

> *SetProperty* will produce a **new** graph with a modified property value.

```
x = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4},
   EdgeWeight -> {1, 10, 30, 60}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", ImagePadding -> 20];
x2 = SetProperty[x, EdgeWeight -> {20, 49, 87, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight], PropertyValue[x2, EdgeWeight]}
(* {{1, 10, 30, 60}, {20, 49, 87, 5}} *)
```

Finally, in `PropertyValue[{x, 1}, EdgeWeight]`, the first argument `{x,1}` is interpreted as *vertex 1* in graph `x` which does not have an `EdgeWeight` property. One should use `PropertyValue[{x, 1<->2}, EdgeWeight]` instead.

```
{PropertyValue[{x2, 1}, EdgeWeight], PropertyValue[{x2, 1 <-> 2}, EdgeWeight]}
(* {$Failed, 20} *)
```

### Version 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit)

I can reproduce the issues on Version 10.1.0 (on Wolfram Programming Cloud). That is,

```
{ PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] = {20, 49, 87, 5}; x,  PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight] }
(* {{20, 49, 87, 5}, {1, 10, 30, 60}} *)
```

and

```
{y = SetProperty[x, EdgeWeight -> {20, 49, 87, 5}],PropertyValue[y, EdgeWeight] }
```

both give

[image]

**Work-arounds:**

```
x = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {1, 10, 30, 60}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

  {(PropertyValue[{x,#}, EdgeWeight] =#2)&@@@ Transpose[{EdgeList[x],{20, 49, 87, 5}}]; 
   x, PropertyValue[x,EdgeWeight]}
```

and

```
x = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1 <-> 2, 3 <-> 2, 3 <-> 4, 1 <-> 4}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {1, 10, 30, 60}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];

{Fold[SetProperty[{#,#2[[1]]},EdgeWeight ->#2[[2]]]&,x,
      Transpose[{EdgeList[x], {20, 49, 87, 5}}]], 
 PropertyValue[x, EdgeWeight]}
```

both give

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bug; do you agree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, yes it does.

Comment: I've gotta say that after all my false "peter and the wolf" accusations (where it turns out I'm just stupid and it's not a bug), it's a little satisfying to finally find a bug. I was pulling out my hair last night for hours trying to figure out what I did wrong. Oh and I added my version number (10) to the OP.

Comment: @kguler, also, I think there may be a typo in your 2nd workaround, if you run that code it throws an error because y2 is undefined.

Comment: One more quick question if that's okay: Your 1st workaround worked great for me, so I tried making a function out of it: ChangeEdgeWeights[gin_, newEWs_] := (pair = {(PropertyValue[{gin, #}, EdgeWeight] = #2) & @@@ 
       Transpose[{EdgeList[gin], newEWs}];
      gin, PropertyValue[gin, EdgeWeight]};
   ];
  Return[First@pair];) But it's giving me an error saying that my input graph "is not a symbol" in the property value assignment. Actually, maybe it's a warning because it still returns the right values. What's the deal with that? Thanks!

Comment: @YungHummmma, Thank you for the accept. I fixed the `y2` typo. You can define `changeEdgeWeights` as ` ClearAll[changeEdgeWeights]; changeEdgeWeights[gin_, newEWs_] := 
 Module[{g = gin}, (PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeWeight] = #2) & @@@ 
   Transpose[{EdgeList[gin], newEWs}]; g]`

Comment: Just in case someone wanders here from MacOS, same issue with 10.3.1 under MacOS as under Unix.